# How to join two javascript variables (dynamically)

Tags: javascript, variables

I call contents from a JSON object which contains values for different sides like side_a = 100, side_b = 200 etc.

Now I want to get the values for every selected side.. this is normally archieved like obj.side_a

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(data); // Inside this are values like side_a, side_b etc.
```

I call each value like

```
obj.side_a
```

Now I want to call this variables inside a loop (the loop returns the available sides - like a, b, c ..), because I just want to display the values of selected sides.

so the 'a' part should be added dynamically to the call..

like obj.side_+sideResultFromTheLoop to get a call like obj.side_a, obj.side_b

I tried it on different ways.. like:

```
obj.+'side_'+theLoopVariable
```

.'obj.*side*'+theLoopVariable

but none of it worked :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different type of syntax with brackets:

```
obj['side_' + theLoopVariable] = objectData;
```

Read more about [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).